# What is Cat & Mouse?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

On your phone, if you to Extras and click on Stats, there's a large amount of information about your various statistics about your game.

On page 10 of 11 at the top of the page, there are two statistics that read as follows:

`Cat & Mouse: Most Points Earned: 0`

`Cat & Mouse: Cash Earned: $0.00`

I've finished the main campaign, and I'm currently working my way through the diversions. I've not heard any mention of "Cat & Mouse" at all. I know it's not a diversion.

What is this? Is it something that is co-op only (I've only played single player)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cat and Mouse is indeed a co-op side mission.  In Saints Row 2, you entered it by killing your co-op partner - the killed partner was then presented with a menu whereby they could choose one of two games to play in retaliation.  Saints Row 3 does something similar.

Cat and Mouse is where one player has a car, and is trying to hit checkpoints similar to a checkpoint race.  The other player has an attack helicopter and has to stop the other player from hitting the checkpoints.  After a set period of time, they switch.  Whoever hit more check points when both timers expire is the winner.

Comment: For me it was a tank on Saints Row the Third, not an attack helicopter.